# What's the most efficient way to migrate this data in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, migration

Here's our current table

```
CREATE TABLE Visitor
(
   VisitorID  bigint,
   DayPhone   varchar(50),
   NightPhone varchar(50)
)
```

I want to migrate this data to a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE VisitorPhone
(
   VisitorID      bigint,
   Label          varchar(50), --Day, Night, Work, Cell, etc.
   Phone          varchar(50)
)
```

My thought was that the most efficient way to would be to do this:

```
INSERT INTO VisitorPhone(VisitorID, Label, Phone)
SELECT VisitorID, 'day', DayPhone FROM dbo.Visitor WHERE DayPhone IS NOT NULL AND DayPhone <> ''

INSERT INTO VisitorPhone(VisitorID, Label, Phone)
SELECT VisitorID, 'night', NightPhone FROM dbo.Visitor WHERE NightPhone IS NOT NULL AND NightPhone <> ''
```

What are my other options? We've talked about everything from Sql CLR functions, Temp Tables, ADO.NET, you name it. What's truly the most efficient way of doing this? Keep in mind that DayPhone, and NightPhone are not part of an index, and that I have 16MM+ visitors records which will equate to somewhere between ~16MM - ~32MM VisitorPhone records.

Comment: Why not having a integer column instead of the varchar label? If you have so many records an int will be smaller and faster... And varchar(50) for a phone-number? Isn't this a little bit to pesimistic?

Comment: I'm not interested in feedback on how I'm storing the data but more on how to migrate it.

Comment: There's a lot of different ways to migrate the data including the ones you mentionned as well as SSIS.  You could profile all of them and find the best way but I would guess that the profiling would take longer than the migration and I would further guess that the INSERT statements you've shown above would be the fastest way.

Comment: A case statement in SQL statement, perhaps ?

Comment: You asked for the most efficient way of doing this. With the wrong choice on the datatype you will not get the most efficient way. Thats the reason I asked. Otherwise your query is pretty much the fastest way

Comment: Is this a onetime conversion? Also, are both DayPhone and NightPhone optional in the current table? Or can any one visitor record generate 0,1 or 2 rows in VisitorPhone?

Comment: It's a one time update. DayPhone and NightPhone are both optional in the VisitorTable. We're migrating to a more flexible storage option for phone numbers. A visitor can have 0 or more phone records in the new structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done the migration like you already suggested. You problem is that a visitor row generates zero, one or two rows in the VisitorPhone table. If it was Oracle, you would have had the "INSERT ALL" syntax which let's you do just this. Maybe some similar syntax is available in SQL Server?

Any procedural approach is likely to be outperformed by a set based approach.

You can do something complicated like joining to a dummy table and determine how many times each Visitor row will be duplicated (0 = has no phone, 1 has either day/night phone, 2 has both). You would then use case-when logic to determine how to encode the row.

30 million rows is not a huge amount of data on something bigger than your typical development laptop. I think that finding and testing an alternative approach would take longer than just execute the two statements. Plus, your current solution is easily documented.

Just be sure to create the indexes afterwards.